# Result count of google search

Tags: android, google-search

Is there a native way (without parsing the web page etc.) to receive the **result count of a google search** in an android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Google search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), which will give you the search results as a JSON object (including totalResults)

Comment: There is difference in count which i think not good to ignore any tricks or tips to overcome ?